# oracle sql developer after creating table , column name came as column1,column2 .... columnN

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i am using sql developer  `Version 21.2.1.204` and when i create table by using new table  function in IDE , and entered name and select type for each field

after clicking on ok button  table is created but fields name are different,

COLUMN2,
COLUMN3,
COLUMN4,

came

i entered column name properly but still this is happening

you can see in images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a known bug.

Answer (score 2):

If the wizard is not working for you, you can write out the DDL statement in a worksheet:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id      VARCHAR2(20),
  name    VARCHAR2(20),
  address VARCHAR2(20),
  age     VARCHAR2(20)     -- Why not use a number?
);
```

And run it.

---

As an aside, you probably should use `date_of_birth` and then calculate the age rather than using an `age` column that will go out of date as soon as the next person reaches their birthday.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id            VARCHAR2(20),
  name          VARCHAR2(20),
  address       VARCHAR2(20),
  date_of_birth DATE
);
```

Comment: age     VARCHAR2(20)     -- Why not use a number? 
ohh no just for giving urgent demo i take this

Comment: here i experience  when type and by mouse i click on next column to edit then working 
but when i use enter key to shift next column name it is not working

Comment: As Jeff says, it's a known bug.  You can read more discussion about it [here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4285555/column1-column2-column3#latest)